# Div dissappears when Dragging from one div to another with scroll overflow using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two "DIV"s, one on the left and one on the right. The right one has draggable elements and the left one has a droppable container. Both DIV's have the CSS attribute `overflow: auto`, which is essential in my implementation because I need a scroll to appear in each div when either DIV overflows.

The issue is, when I drag the element in the right DIV, and move it to the left, it disappears after the edge of the DIV.

This is a sample of what I'm trying to do.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Practice</title>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(function() {
      for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        $('#right').append($('<div></div>')
          .addClass('item')
          .html(i));

      }
      $(".item").draggable({
        cursor: "move",
        revert: "invalid"
      });
      $("#bin").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
          var mydiv = $(ui.draggable);
          $("#bin").html("Dropped");
        }
      });
    });
  </script>

  <style>
    #left {
      border: 2px solid black;
      position: fixed;
      width: 49%;
      height: 98%;
      overflow: auto;
    }
    #right {
      border: 2px solid black;
      position: fixed;
      left: 52%;
      top: 2%;
      width: 46%;
      height: 98%;
      overflow: auto;
    }
    #bin {
      border: 2px solid black;
      position: relative;
      left: 12%;
      top: 5%;
      width: 75%;
      height: 75%;
    }
    .item {
      border: 2px solid black;
      left: 12%;
      top: 5%;
      width: 15%;
      height: 5%;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="left">
    <div id="bin">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="right">




  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Something like this or not ? https://jsfiddle.net/8k21bsu8/

Comment: Not exactly, the issue is when you drag it to the left out of its parent DIV (the right DIV), it disappears behind the other content.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the overflow:auto in your CSS. You will then see the item will be visible when dragging between the divs then.

In order to accomplish the functionality you'd like, you need an outer div wrapping the two container boxes. You'd set an fixed height on the outer div, then use overflow-y:scroll to get your functionality.

Comment: but then wont the two inner divs share the scroll? I need each div to have a separate scroll.

Comment: No, the divs would not share the scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as others have suggested, but I've always found the best way to accomplish this is to set the draggable item to `position:fixed`

see for example:
https://jsfiddle.net/gregborbonus/tzz0927p/1/

For me personally, this allowed a lot more flexibility, but I also did a lot of work with responsive designs and such to make it work right.

I've edited to include overlapping div's. Added a few functions to make it more visible, like random Color, and an on hover and hover out event to make it possible to see and click each box.

https://jsfiddle.net/gregborbonus/tzz0927p/3/

With 100 and added a scroll function to make the scroll smooth. Also added a quick snippet so that the elements would only appear within the containing box.

This is different from your code, it uses 2 containers, rightc for the main container(the one that scrolls) and right for the container of all the elements. The rest is commented in the code.

https://jsfiddle.net/gregborbonus/tzz0927p/13/

so, something I realized was that the elements would still overlap the page on page load.

So, to show this working with an even shorter div and changed to compensate for onload:

https://jsfiddle.net/gregborbonus/tzz0927p/15/

Comment: This would be a great idea if I didn't need the elements to stack over each other and eventually have a scroll overflow on the y-axis. Check out the updated code

Comment: take the case pf 50 instead of 20 elements, then you wont be able to access the overflown elements...However, I need a scroll to appear in case of an overflow.

Comment: check out the last version